# Which form of relative import to prefer inside a package

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a library named *Foo* for an example.

The `__init__.py` file:

```
from .foo_exceptions import *
from .foo_loop import FooLoop()
main_loop = FooLoop()
from .foo_functions import *

__all__ = ['main_loop'] + foo_exceptions.__all__ + foo_functions.__all__
```

When installed, it can be used like this:

```
# example A
from Foo import foo_create, main_loop

foo_obj = foo_create()
main_loop().register(foo_obj)
```

or like this:

```
# example B
import Foo

foo_obj = Foo.foo_create()
Foo.main_loop().register(foo_obj)
```

I clearly prefer the example B approach. No name conflicts and the source of each external object is explicitely stated.

---

So much for introduction, now my question. Inside this library I need to import something from a different file. Again, I have several ways to do it. And the question is which style to prefer - C, D or E? Read below.

```
# example C
from . import foo_exceptions

raise foo_exceptions.FooError("fail")
```

or

```
# example D
from .foo_exceptions import FooError

raise FooError("fail")
```

or

```
# example E
from . import FooError

raise FooError("fail")
```

---

Approach C has the disadvantage, that importing a whole module instead of importing just a few required objects increases the chance of a cyclical import problem. Also consider this line:

```
from . import foo_exceptions, main_loop
```

It looks like an import of 2 symbols from one source, but it isn't. The former (`foo_exceptions`) is a module (.py file) in the current directory and the latter is an object defined in `__init__.py`.

That's why I'm not using style C and the question in its final form is: D or E (and why)?

*(Thank you for reading this long question. All code fragments are examples only and may contain typos)*

---

After the answer from alexanderlukanin:

- EDIT1: corrected errors in init.py
- NOTE1: foo_ prefixes are only to emphasize the relationship between objects

---

- EDIT2: When importing an object which is **not** part of the library interface, style E is not usable. I think we have a winner: It's the `from .module import symbol` form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use old-style [relative imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/):

   ```
   # Import from foo/foo_loop.py
   # This DOES NOT WORK in Python 3
   # and MAY NOT WORK AS EXPECTED in Python 2
   from foo_loop import FooLoop

   # This is reliable and unambiguous
   from .foo_loop import FooLoop
   ```
2. Don't use asterisk import unless you *really* have to.

   ```
   # Namespace pollution! Name clashes!
   from .submodule import *
   ```
3. Don't use prefixes - you've got namespaces exactly for that purpose.

   ```
   # Unpythonic
   from foo import foo_something_create
   foo_something_create()

   # Pythonic
   import foo.something
   foo.something.create()
   ```
4. Your package's API must be well-defined. Your implementation must not be too tangled. The rest is a matter of taste.

   ```
   # [C] This is good.
   # Import order: __init__.py, exceptions.py
   from . import exceptions
   raise exceptions.FooError

   # [D] This is also fine.
   # Import order is the same as above,
   # only name binding inside the current module is different.
   from .exceptions import FooError
   raise FooError

   # [E] This is not as good because it adds one unnecessary level of indirection
   # submodule.py -> __init__.py -> exceptions.py
   from . import FooError
   raise FooError
   ```

See also: [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 1: OK, this is obvious in Python3. 2: I do `import *` only when the module was written for it, i.e. it defines `__all__` . Actually in `__init__.py` of a package makes the `import *` sense, doesn't it? 3: I used the prefixes just to make my example code clearer. I do not use them normally, so we are in agreement here; 4: good point against E in my D or E question. Thanks.

Comment: Now I see, that your point 1 was a reaction to my `__init__.py`  containing errors. I have corrected them. I'm using Python 3 only, it would not work.